# Pandas compare items in list in one column with single value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Consider this two column df.  I would like to create an apply function that compares each item in the "other_yrs" column list with the single integer in the "cur" column and keeps count of each item in the "other_yrs" column list that is greater than or equal to the single value in the "cur" column.  I cannot figure out how to enable pandas to do this with apply.  I am using apply functions for other purposes and they are working well.  Any ideas would be very appreciated.

```
    cur other_yrs
1   11  [11, 11]
2   12  [16, 13, 12, 9, 9, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]
4   16  [15, 85]
5   17  [17, 17, 16]
6   13  [8, 8]
```

Below is the function I used to extract the values into the "other_yrs" column.  I am thinking I can just insert into this function some way of comparing each successive value in the list with the "cur" column value and keep count.  I really only need to store the count of how many of the list items are <= the value in the "cur" column.

```
def col_check(col_string):
cs_yr_lst = []
count = 0
if len(col_string) < 1:  #avoids col values of 0 meaning no other cases.
    pass
else:
    case_lst = col_string.split(", ")  #splits the string of cases into a list
    for i in case_lst:
        cs_yr = int(i[3:5])  #gets the case year from each individual case number
        cs_yr_lst.append(cs_yr)  #stores those integers in a list and then into a new column using apply
return cs_yr_lst
```

The expected output would be this:

```
  cur other_yrs    count
1   11  [11, 11]     2
2   12  [16, 13, 12, 9, 9, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]   11
4   16  [15, 85]     1
5   17  [17, 17, 16] 3
6   13  [8, 8]  2
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @anky Great point.  I edited the question just now.  The expected output is simply a count of each value in the list that is <= the single value in the "cur" column.

Comment: thank you. how does row `2` have 10 as count.. are we considering unique counts?

Comment: @anky user error.  That should read 11.  The count represents all list values < or = the value in the "cur" column.  Fixed it.  Not considering unique counts.  If a list has multiple number 3s, for example, each of them would increment the count value by 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `zip` inside a list comprehension to zip the columns `cur` and `other_yrs` and use `np.sum` on boolean mask:

```
df['count'] = [np.sum(np.array(b) <= a) for a, b in zip(df['cur'], df['other_yrs'])]
```

Another idea:

```
df['count'] = pd.DataFrame(df['other_yrs'].tolist(), index=df.index).le(df['cur'], axis=0).sum(1)
```

Result:

```
   cur                                   other_yrs  count
1   11                                    [11, 11]      2
2   12  [16, 13, 12, 9, 9, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]     11
4   16                                    [15, 85]      1
5   17                                [17, 17, 16]      3
6   13                                      [8, 8]      2
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Just a confirmation follow up.  Your answer worked perfectly!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Great. Happy coding John!

Answer (score 2):

You can consider `explode` and compare then group on level=0 and sum:

```
u = df.explode('other_yrs')
df['Count'] = u['cur'].ge(u['other_yrs']).sum(level=0).astype(int)
```

---

```
print(df)
    cur                                   other_yrs  Count
1   11                                    [11, 11]      2
2   12  [16, 13, 12, 9, 9, 6, 6, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0]     11
4   16                                    [15, 85]      1
5   17                                [17, 17, 16]      3
6   13                                      [8, 8]      2
```

Comment: So, explode creates a series then?

Comment: @JohnTaylor explode transforms each element of a list-like to a row, replicating index value.

Answer (score 0):

If columns contain millions of records in both of the dataframes and one has to compare each element in first column with all the elements in the second column then following code might be helpful.

```
for element in Dataframe1.Column1:
    
   Dataframe2[Dateframe2.Column2.isin([element])]
```

Above code snippet will return one by one specific rows of dataframe2 where element from dataframe1 is found in dataframe2.column2.